# Automatic Redirect URL in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have problem with URL in Laravel 5.2

If I type the url directly to the browser, it works fine. However, if I hyperlink the url, it reduces the url and returns to another link.

For example:

**firstsite.com/juliet/tasks** will become **firstsite.com/tasks** when I click on a hyperlink.

Here are my *.htaccess* file under Laravel root folder (not public folder):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It works when I try the absolute url:

```
<a href="http://firstsite.com/juliet/tasks"><div class="btn btn-warning">Back</div></a>
```

This one doesn't work although when I hover the mouse to the button, it does show the correct hyperlink which is **firstsite.com/juliet/tasks**:

```
<a href="/juliet/tasks"><div class="btn btn-warning">Back</div></a>
```